# React Native iOS build succeeds locally but fails on CI server

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, azure-devops

I recently updated a React Native project to version 0.59, and the built-in `AsyncStorage` is now deprecated. So I installed the `@react-native-community/react-native-async-storage` package instead as advised, and linked the packages by running `react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage`.

The build now succeeds when running it in Xcode locally. However, when I try to run the build in my CI pipeline in Azure DevOps, it fails during linking:

```
# ...

▸ Compiling main.m
▸ Linking MyApp
⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/agent/2.149.2/work/1/s/ios/MyApp/System/Library/Frameworks'

❌  ld: library not found for -lRNCAsyncStorage



❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


▸ Linking MyApp
⚠️  ld: directory not found for option '-L/Users/vsts/agent/2.149.2/work/1/s/ios/MyApp/System/Library/Frameworks'

❌  ld: library not found for -lRNCAsyncStorage



❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-asjjausbybqgpsdjodrbvoyzaeqx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/BetaRelease-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp normal armv7
    Ld /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-asjjausbybqgpsdjodrbvoyzaeqx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/MyApp.build/BetaRelease-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MyApp normal arm64
(2 failures)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build, sign and export
```

Further up it does look like it has been built:

```
# ...

▸ Building RNCAsyncStorage/RNCAsyncStorage [(Release)]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Building library libRNCAsyncStorage.a
▸ Building library libRNCAsyncStorage.a
▸ Copying RNCAsyncStorage.h
▸ Copying RNCAsyncStorageDelegate.h

# ...
```

Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Deployment Target to 11.0 in Build Settings / Deployment / iOS Deployment Target.

[What might be happening](https://github.com/janeasystems/nodejs-mobile/issues/42)

I was having the exact same issue with a different library and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this `${PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/RNCAsyncStorage` to `Library Search Paths` worked for me.

[image]